# oidc-client - uses own URL for login

Tags: keycloak, oidc-client

I have small `vue` app that authenticate users with `Keycloak` backend.
I use `oidc-client` to redirect clients to authentication page.

Whenever the login logic triggers, the URL uses client's url and not the authority. (all query params are correct).

this is the URL on browser:

[image]

this is my code (simplified and without URL):

```
import Oidc from "oidc-client";

let config = {
    authority: "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9855/auth/realms/AvosetGo_Tests",
    client_id: "CLIENT-ID",
    redirect_uri: "localhost:4200/callback",
    response_type: "code",
    scope: "openid profile email",
    post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:4200/",
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    filterProtocolClaims: true,
    loadUserInfo: true
};
const mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(config);

export const authManager = {
    signin: async () => {
        const user = await mgr.getUser();
        console.log("this is is " + user);
        if (!user) {
            await mgr.signinRedirect();
        }
    }
}
```